# Minimize the fault\error when converting polar and cartesian java

Tags: java, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I use this code to convert from polar to cartesian and vice versa :

```
    final double alpha = Math.atan2(y - originY, x - originX);
    final int checkx = originX + (int) (radiusW * (Math.cos(alpha)));
    final int checky = originY + (int) (radiusH * (Math.sin(alpha)));
    final double newAlpha = Math.atan2(checky - originY, checkx - originX);
    double fault = Math.toDegrees(newAlpha) - Math.toDegrees(alpha);
```

Using this, i get fault that can reach 15 degrees, can it be better?

Thanks!

EDIT :

```
    final double alpha = Math.atan2(y - originY, x - originX);
    final double checkx = originX +  (radiusW * (Math.cos(alpha)));
    final double checky = originY +  (radiusH * (Math.sin(alpha)));
    final double newAlpha = Math.atan2(checky - originY, checkx - originX);
    double fault = Math.toDegrees(newAlpha) - Math.toDegrees(alpha);
```

Tried that still same error...

For example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int originY = 700;
    int originX = 500;
    int radiusW = 500;
    int radiusH = 700;
    int y = 800;
    int x = 600;
    final double alpha = Math.atan2(y - originY, x - originX);
    final double checkx = originX + (radiusW * (Math.cos(alpha)));
    final double checky = originY + (radiusH * (Math.sin(alpha)));
    final double newAlpha = Math.atan2(checky - originY, checkx - originX);
    System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(newAlpha) - Math.toDegrees(alpha));
}
```

Output :

9.462322208025618

Comment: Yes.  Don't convert the cartesian x and y to integers.  Leave them as doubles.

Comment: Why are you using `int` for `checkx` and `checky`?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc tried, didnt help...

Comment: What output, specifically, are you looking for?

Comment: @DaveNewton Im looking for as small error as possible, see i save points on cartesian and sometimes need to do some calculations on them using its polar reps and then convert back to cartesian but this kind of error is noticeable on GUI...

Comment: Why do have both `radiusW` and `radiusH`?  Shouldn't you have a single `r` with `r^2 = (y - originY) ^2 +  (x - originX)^2`? Maybe I need to see a picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm asking what is the specific output you want for what you've shown. I mean, Java math is normal floating point math.

Comment: What _are_ radiusW and radiusH, and why are they exactly equal to originX and originY in your example?  If you are going to convert given cartesian coordinates x and y to polar form, then you should be _computing_ a radius along with the angle that you compute.